# Using Apache PDFBox for extracting text getting wrong charecters?

Tags: java, pdfbox

**I'm trying to extract text from PDF using Apache PDFBox 1.8.4 - my code is bellow:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("rep.pdf"));
        PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        String s =  stripper.getText(pdfDocument);
        System.out.println(s);
        pdfDocument.close();
    }
```

pdf which want to convert: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t35rr23v4383yvt/Form-V-report.pdf?dl=0

but got such charecters:

```
!"#$%&'()*$+,)!'-,./+/
0+12)3$#'(,,)451#+('1)65+7(,+'(/
!"#$%&'(
)*+,-.##(',/$.0
123.4.5,67,,89:;+
<3$'(=,>:++?,*99%@AB)
```

Any solutions?

In Advance - Thanks.

Comment: Read  https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/faq.html#gibberish . Btw your version is outdated. (Although the current version can't extract your text either)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adobe has integrated PDF obfuscation which can be enabled by the creator of PDFs. I can't recall exactly how it works, but you will find similar issues if you use any of the online PDF text-extraction tools, or if you try and copy and paste the text.

You likely need to either:

A) Ask for a copy without this enabled

or

B) Need to reverse engineer how it is done, and use that knowledge to reverse it.

I have a feeling A is the right answer

Comment: I tried to run `qpdf --stream-data=uncompress Form-V-report.pdf unompressed-report.pdf` to get the content in plain text, but it did not help. The content is still gibberish.

Comment: Yeah, it's not going to matter what you put the PDF through it will do it. The best bet would be to convert it to some images and use an OCR application to do it, rather than trying to extract the text. It's the result of the obfuscation I talked about.

Comment: *Adobe has integrated PDF obfuscation which can be enabled by the creator of PDFs* - This is an interesting way to put it. More common is the perspective that says that the format PDF is for *displaying* documents; to allow extra features like *text extraction*, extra information has to be added to the PDF or specific, standard glyph IDs have to be used. Obfuscation can indeed be implemented by failing to provide that information.

Comment: Pretty much, although I think it may be the other way around and that this is done explicitly to stop extraction. Not that it makes much difference.

Comment: Ah, but it *does make a difference*: If the software generating the PDF considers this a *feature*, it likely can be switched off as you proposed as **A** and the OP may hope for a version with text extraction enabled. If this merely is a side effect or implementation detail, though, there likely is not option to switch on or off to retrieve a document with text extraction enabled, so your proposal is doomed to fail.

Comment: By the way, **B** fails because the font glyphs have lost all their relation to some Unicode value, they are arranged in an ad-hoc manner: the first glyph used on the page is the first in the font, the second, different one used is the second in the font, etc etc.

Comment: mkl: that's how I assumed it worked, although I imagined it was something like caesers cypher with unicode characters (vignettes cypher?). If it can be read by the computer I'm assuming it can be reverse engineered.

But I am certain it is an option you can disable when producing the PDF because I have certainly edited PDFs in this manner before, and the only ones where I couldn't were ones I expected to be protected (i.e court transcripts).